# I want to load another view file after the url / but receiving an error saying page not found

Tags: python, django

**Error message**:

> Page not found (404)
> Request Method: GET
> Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/music/2/
> Using the URLconf defined in Analytic_practice.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/
> music/ [name='index']
> music/ (?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/ [name='detail']
> The current path, music/2/, didn't match any of these.

Here is my code:

**music.urls.py file**:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('(?P<album_id>[0-9]+)/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>This will be a list of all Albums</h1>")
# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def detail(request, album_id):
    return HttpResponse("<h2>Details for Album id: " + str(album_id) + "</h2>")
```

**Analytic_practice.urls.py**:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('music/', include('music.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 3):

You are messing `path` with `re_path`. As, `id` only contains `integer`. So:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:album_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
]
```

[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/#example)